# Core Data Drill down table

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm working with `Core Data` and I was hoping you can help me with a problem I'm having. The Example is let say I have 3 entities Make and Model, Options, and image of car with multiple attributes. There can be 1 Make, multiple Options and 1 image per Option. What I want to happen is if there is only one Option skip the Options in the drill down and go straight to the image. Example is:

```
Table of more than one Option
make - Model | Options | Photo
Chevy Camaro  ->  LS  ->  Image of Car.
Chevy Camaro  ->  LT  ->  Image of Car.

table of one Option 

Chevy Blazer  -> Image of Car
```

This is how I envisioned doing it

This is the if statement

```
if(options > 1 || count.totalCount == 0)
    {
        //
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"multipleDetails" sender:self];

    }else
    {
        [self loadImage];
        Image *link = [_urlFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        webViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webView"];
        detailViewController.webData = link.link;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

   }
```

and this is the part that fetches the data.

```
- (void)loadMakeModel {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MakeModel" inManagedObjectContext:localContext]];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(make == %@)",currentMake];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];

    //NSLog(@"fetch request: %@",fetchRequest);
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:40];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Model" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:localContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}

- (void)loadOptions {
    [self loadMakeModel];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    optionTitle = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *options = [MakeModel MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"OptionTitle" withValue:optionTitle.makeTitle];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FCOptions" inManagedObjectContext:localContext]];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(options == %@)",options];
    //
    [fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];

    _optionsFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:localContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    [_optionsFetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];


}
- (void)loadImage {
    [self loadOptions];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ImageUrl = [_optionsFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CarImage" inManagedObjectContext:localContext]];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(url == %@)",ImageUrl.url];
    //
    [fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"url" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];

    _urlFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:localContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    [_urlFetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

}
```

The problem is the `optionTitle` is nil for some reason.
Any help or example would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is die problem with that? Probably you better show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fiqured it out by using:

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];`

instead of

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`